TYPO3 EXT:Form Finisher EmailToRecipient does not read my configured senderAddress
TYPO3 11
I configured a form with the assistant. The YAML file is stored in fileadmin as usual. The form contains fields for firstname (identifier 'text-1'), lastname (identifier 'text-2') and email (identifier 'email-1').
I added the finisher 'EmailToRecipient' and entered {email-1} as SenderAddress and {text-1} and {text-2} as SenderName.
With this setup I got the error message Sender address rejected: Message rejected due to: SPF fail - not authorized. Sender not authorized
Which is understandable. So I changed the SenderAddress to the default email address the server is configured to use. But the form does not recognize this change. It always takes {email-1} as SenderAddress.
Why is that so? What am I missing here?
Here is the finisher part of the YAML file:
finishers:
  -
    options:
      subject: '[TYPO3-Server] Here is an email to you'
      recipients:
        info@mydomain.de: 'My Name'
      senderAddress: 'typo3@mydomain.de'
      senderName: 'TYPO3-Server'
      addHtmlPart: true
      attachUploads: false
      translation:
        language: Standard
      useFluidEmail: false
      title: ''
    identifier: EmailToReceiver

I can debug what the finisher really takes as options. It is:
senderAddress => '{email-1}'
senderName => '{text-4} {text-5}'

Any ideas arround?

You very likely have finisher overrides enabled in the form plugin. Here you should find {email-1} as sender address. Either disable the finisher overrides altogether or update this value accordingly.
